# How to connect to MongoDB using SoapUI JDBC Test Step?

Tags: mongodb, jdbc, driver, soapui

I am using SoapUI for testing REST/SOAP services. At a point I need to connect to MongoDB and extract some value from the db.

I am stuck with initializing the db.

Error Snippet below:

```
com.eviware.soapui.support.SoapUIException: Failed to init connection for driver[com.mongodb.mongo], connectionString [mongodb://<userName>:<pwd>@<domain>:<port>/<collectionName>]
```

I am unable to invoke connection.

**What all I have done?**

1. I have installed the mongoDB driver "mongodb-driver-3.0.0" @ "C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.1.2\bin\ext"
2. Below is the screenshot of how I am trying to achieve it
   [image: SoapUI Screenshot of JDBC Test Step used to invoke mongoDB]

The SoapUI Logs as follows:

```
    Sun Jun 07 14:39:24 IST 2015:ERROR:An error occurred [No suitable driver], see error log for details

Sun Jun 07 14:39:24 IST 2015:ERROR:java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
   java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(Unknown Source)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.jdbc.JdbcUtils.initConnection(JdbcUtils.java:51)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.JdbcRequestTestStepDesktopPanel$TestConnectionAction.actionPerformed(JdbcRequestTestStepDesktopPanel.java:616)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

All i could see at first place is inability to connect through driver class of mongoDB.

Comment: Did you install a JDBC driver? Did you define it in the properties? How are you connecting?

Comment: @SiKing

1. I did installed JDBC driver "mongodb-driver-3.0.0" in "C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.1.2\bin\ext". 

2. I  tried adding it to Flie > Preferences in SoapUI but couldn't find any option there.

3. I am trying to connect mongoDB through JDBC Test Step available in SoapUI Test Case.

Comment: Have a read through here: http://www.soapui.org/jdbc/getting-started.html

Comment: I had successfully connected to mysql through JDBC test step. All i need is driver name to get connected to mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

A possible option is installing **sleepy mongoose** on your mongodb therefore it can respond to HTTP/REST request. Then you can pull whatever information you want directly from mongo using the HTTP request test step in SOAPUI.

Let me know if this was helpful.

Comment: Thanks @Dimitri, though I have access to only one collection from the db installed at third party. I have not installed mongoDB locally. I am providing the domain name to reach to db and fetch the result. 

The issue encounter is inability to create connection with mongoDB, I am not able to call the driver class of mongodb. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use below groovy code in "Groovy test step" of your test case and connect to mongodb. Before that please ensure that mongodb java client jar file and gmongo are in {Installation Directory}\bin\ext folder of your soapUI installation

Gmongo: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.gmongo/gmongo/1.5

Mongodb Java Client : http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.2.2

```
import com.gmongo.GMongoClient
import com.gmongo.GMongo
import com.mongodb.MongoCredential
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress

//def credentials = MongoCredential.createMongoCRCredential('admin', 'students', 'admin' as char[])

//def client = new GMongoClient(new ServerAddress("127.0.0.1:27017"))

context.gmongo=new GMongo()
def db=context.gmongo.getDB("test")
log.info db.fruit.find().count()

db.fruit.find().each{

    doc->log.info doc

    }
```